# RHEL 7.5 text based install on H/W - Installation Destination "No disks selected"

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

We are using RHEL 7.5 customized for our use and install
We have our own kickstart which uses list-harddrives and parted to  check on the Disks  and partition accordingly. Disks are in RAID 10 configuration
Intermettently  we see that the  Installation destination  "No disk selected".
REbooting the system and trying again - this works and install goes thru with a  question.
Any suggestions on how to debug this further - and what are the possible points to check

```
=============================================================================

Installation

 1) [x] Language settings                 2) [x] Time settings
        (English (United States))                (America/Los_Angeles timezone)
 3) [x] Installation source               4) [x] Software selection
        (Local media)                            (Custom software selected)
 5) [!] Installation Destination          6) [x] Kdump
        (No disks selected)                      (Kdump is disabled)
 7) [ ] Network configuration             8) [ ] User creation
        (Not connected)                          (No user will be created)
=============================================================================
```